# Salesforce CRM API intergration

Tags: yii2, salesforce

I am new for Salesforce CRM. I want to integrate API for Salesforce for that I have created a developer app and get consumer key and consumer secret. I am using yii2.

Which API should I use?? REST or SOAP???

Whenever m running below the line in my terminal it returns invalid client response.

`curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=YOURCONSUMERID&redirect_uri=https://www.yourappname.com/api/callback`

Here, in place of YOURCONSUMERID I am sending my salesforce App's consumer key.

My client Id is valid still it returns me a response like,

`error=invalid_client_id&error_description=client%20identifier%20invalid`

---

Comment: Your redirect_uri needs to match the one configured in your Connected App. You'll probably want to use REST API unless you specifically prefer using SOAP in a strongly-typed language.

Comment: My redirect uri is also correct, i have copied it from my app page.

Comment: You have to check the app permission